# android, how to create a custom UI to show on top of the lockscreen

Tags: android, android-widget, lockscreen

In android app, currently when received the notification, after call the `pm.notify(...)` a notification will be shown in the drawer.

when the device is on lockscreen and receives notification, it would like to have the notification to be displayed in a custom UI (on top of the lockscreen, maybe like a dialog popup, but not the notification shown in the notification drawer), and update the content of this UI when later received next notification.

Is it possible, and how to achieve this?